# Multi thread for joystick input

Tags: c#, multithreading, sharpdx

Hi there i am trying to make a question answer game. ( Whoever presses joystick button first answers the question first )

So far i ' ve used SharpDX , threading since i cant handle the button press event via SharpDX

My problem is i cant get it worked . I dont know the reason but let me explain my code.

On my page load i ' ve initialized 2 different threads ;

```
//Initializing the constants 

    private bool q = true;
    private Thread th1;
    private Thread th2;
    private Guid joy1Guid = Guid.Empty;
    private Guid joy2Guid = Guid.Empty;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var directInput = new DirectInput();

        foreach (var deviceInstance in directInput.GetDevices())
        {
            if (deviceInstance.Subtype == 258)
            {


//My joysticks connected to pc via usb.
                if (joy1Guid == Guid.Empty)
                    joy1Guid = deviceInstance.InstanceGuid;
                else if (joy2Guid == Guid.Empty)
                    joy2Guid = deviceInstance.InstanceGuid;
            }
        }

        th1 = new Thread(Joy1Start);
        th2 = new Thread(Joy2Start);
        th1.IsBackground = true;
        th2.IsBackground = true;
    }
```

Below my Thread methods

```
  private void Joy1Start()
    {
        var directInput = new DirectInput();

        var joystick = new Joystick(directInput, joy1Guid);
        joystick.Properties.BufferSize = 128;
        joystick.Acquire();

        while (q)
        {
            joystick.Poll();

            var state = joystick.GetCurrentState();
            var counter = 0;
            foreach (bool isPressed in state.Buttons)
            {
                if (isPressed)
                {
                    Action a1 = () => textBox1.Text = "JOY1";
                    textBox1.Invoke(a1);
                    th1.Abort();
                    th2.Abort();
                    q = false;
                    break;
                }
                counter++;
            }

        }

    }
    private void Joy2Start()
    {

        var directInput = new DirectInput();

        var joystick = new Joystick(directInput, joy2Guid);
        joystick.Properties.BufferSize = 128;
        joystick.Acquire(); 
        while (q)
        {
            joystick.Poll();

            var state = joystick.GetCurrentState();
            var counter = 0;
            foreach (bool isPressed in state.Buttons)
            {
                if (isPressed)
                {
                    Action a2 = () => textBox1.Text = "JOY2";
                    textBox1.Invoke(a2);
                    th1.Abort(); 
                    q = false;
                    break;
                }
                counter++;
            }

        } 
    }
```

I am firing thread starts with a button

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        th1.Start();
        th2.Start();

    }
```

So the problem is i can't get any response if i work with two threads.

When i only start th1 or th2 it works like a charm.

Can you please show me where is the wrong part of this algorithm ?

Comment: Why does this require threading? Can't you deal with both joysticks on the same thread?

Comment: @BenAaronson You need to have while loops for getting the states of joysticks. I want to know which joystick pressed button first so i 've chosen threading

Comment: Why not have one thread poll for joystick button pressing?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov How can i know which joystick ( user ) pressed any button first ?